# Conditional Formatting on a Specific Character only

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have the following Excel table :

```
>          N

1    Open / Closed

2          O

3          C

4          O

5          O

6          C
```

I want to put a Conditional Formatting, putting in GREEN the rows with a "C" (C is Closed) and in RED the rows with a "O" (O is Opened).

I'm using the method of appliance by specific text. However, if I put the whole column "N" in the Area of appliance, my Text "Open - Closed" ends up RED or GREEN depending on the order of the rules.

Is there a way to put specifically one character in the rules ? I've tried "C" with quotation marks, but I doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry, you want to conditionally format the cell, but have the different text within it be formatted differently? e.g. - `<green>O</green>pen / <red>C</red>losed` ?

Comment: No, I want the O to be Red, the C to be Green but the Open / Closed to be black

Comment: So you want to format only cells that contain a single character?

Comment: The easiest way would be to put a third rule after the first two that looks for characters that aren't O or C and set those to no format

Comment: `No, I want the O to be Red, the C to be Green but the Open / Closed to be black` I wish you had put that in the OP - it's much easier to understand than the 3 paragraphs you wrote!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `Specific Text`, try using `Cell Value` and `equal to`, then enter `C` for one rule and `O` for the other *(do not enter `equal` or `quotes` when entering the letter, Excel does it for you)*. This will look for the only the letters that match.

[image]

[image]

Applied to the whole column, this ignores text of the `Open / Closed` heading.

[image]